# Download progress with a logging callback?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure-storage

I have a headscratcher of a challenge here.

I have a web application running in Azure, that at some point will expose a SAS URI (download link) for users to download files from our Azure Storage.

The problem with this is that I cannot keep track of an exact count of the content downloaded.

I can only assume that when I produce a download link for a certain user, the file was completely downloaded. Which perhaps wasn't.

I've looked at Azure logs and I don't think I could find what I want in there.

Is there any way I could have the user download the file from a controller method, and have a callback being executed every once in a while that would hold the transfer progress so I could log it somewhere and know which user download that much.

I'm thinking SignalR too. Could this be used for this purpose ?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385633/serving-large-files-with-c-sharp-httplistener

Comment: Don't think so. The HttpListener dies when the request is done.

Comment: No. It is up to you. It can run forever (see the infinite loop in the answer)

Answer (score 0):

> The problem with this is that I cannot keep track of an exact count of the content downloaded.

If [Azure storage diagnostics feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-monitor-storage-account) is turned on, the read/write/delete operations on blob will be logged, you can get download (`getblob` operation) count for the specified blob from diagnostics logs.

Besides, if users are only enabled to download blobs from your MVC application, you can update & save download count in an external storage in your controller action, and [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787579/how-to-detect-or-count-azure-blob-downloads) discussed a similar issue. If you expose SAS URI directly, user who has a valid and not-expired SAS URI can enter that SAS URI in browser and download the blob, it will be difficult to trace the download count of blobs that is downloaded in this way.