# Download count of files from Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Is it possible to get a download count of files stored in Azure Blog Storage? eg

- file 1: 10 downloads
- file 2: 12 downloads

I can see raw download logs on Blob storage using Azure Storage Explorer:

[image]

then:
[image]

I've tried Log Analytics but can't seem to pull in that data

[image]

I can get a sum of the total transactions, but can't see a way of getting the specific filenames in.

[image]

Commenter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787579/how-to-detect-or-count-azure-blob-downloads) is asking the same question.

Comment: did you managed this somehow?

Comment: Hi @bilak - yes I did with https://davemateer.com/2018/11/07/Azure-Functions-to-Count-Downloads-from-Blob-Storage